# How can you add to cart only if matching product id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an item to a list only if that item matches the id. Meaning that only one item would get added to the cart. I've tried doing this in a couple of ways but can't seem to find a way for react to detect my item's id.

Here is my code: I'm trying to map through my data's file which is where I have the info about the product and then with that info if it matches the id, I'm trying to push it to the item's array. But this does nothing...

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {products} = data
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const [item, setItem] = useState([])

  const addCart = (products) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.map((product) => {
        if (product.id === data.id) {
          setItem(item.push(product))
        }
      })
  }


    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={data.id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={data.id}>
                <button onClick={addCart}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

Yes this is my data object:

```
import diCaprio from './img/diCaprio.jpg'
import steveJobs from './img/steveJobs.jpg'
import lips from './img/lips.jpg'
import buda from './img/buda.jpg'
import spaceDog from './img/spaceDog.jpg'
import astroNube from './img/astroNube.jpg'
import banksy from './img/Banksy.jpg'
import banksyDJ from './img/banksyDJ.jpg'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');


const data = [{
  id: uniqid(),
  title: "Steve Jobs",
  img: steveJobs,
  homeImg: steveJobs,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: diCaprio,
  homeImg: diCaprio,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: lips,
  homeImg: lips,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: buda,
  homeImg: buda,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: spaceDog,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:astroNube,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: banksy,
  button: "add to cart"
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:banksyDJ,
  button: "add to cart"
}
]

export default data;
```

Comment: did you check my updated answer?

Comment: yes working fine! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `data` object doesnt have a `products` property so this line of code for object destructuring is useless.

```
  const {products} = data
```

You need to change your button to pass the `id` on click

```
      {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
        <>
          <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
          <div key={id}>
            <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
```

and then handle it accordingly in your method

```
  const addCart = (productId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.id === productId) {
          setItem(item.push(product))
        }
      })
  }
```

Also, you don't need `map` in this iteration but `forEach`

Comment: Why do you need a forEach in this case? Also, this is giving me an empty array...

Comment: sorry i don'thave any more info to help you better. what do your data objects look like? post a json. thnx

Comment: it seems that data is an object with a property `products` which has all the info?

Comment: ok now it's more clear. check my updated answer